# reset my structure to initial values or null values

Tags: swift, struct

I want to clear my structure.
I want to reset all the values to nil.
How do i do this???

```
enum HealthDataType: String, Codable {
      case heartRate
      case bmi
  }
 

  struct HealthDataItem: Codable {
      let endDate: String
      let value: String
      let startDate: String
      let type: HealthDataType
    
  }
```

Comment: You can't set the values to `nil` because they are non-optional. To keep the struct members non-optional you could set the strings to `""` and add an enum case `none` (optional enums are bad practice), otherwise make everything optional.

Comment: Typically you just create a new struct instance. Making all the properties of a type optional just to support this isn't the right way to go IMO, because it just complicates the purpose of the type